# 2 фильтра на массив в 1 функции VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Хотела на массив повесить 2 фильтра. Логика такая: 
1 - фильтр для поиска. При вводе названия, массив "перерисовывается" и обратно.
2 - при клике на чекбокс, массив также фильтруется, в зависимости от того, какое у чекбокса значение: true или false. (если true, то объект массива в основном списке пропадает и отрисовывается в списке "просмотренные")

Обе функции (для фильтрации при "поиске" и для фильтрации в основном списке и отрисовке в новом) у меня уже есть. (функция для фильтрации в зависимости от true/false прописана в закомменченном коде в той же функции  с первым фильтром) 
Каждая по отдельности правильно работает. НО
Я не знаю, как мне 2 эти функции соединить в одну.

Занимаюсь 3 недели в целом, на вью около 2 недель. Не судите строго пожалуйста

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        movies: [
            {
                'film': "Мстители, 2012",
                'seen': false,
                'id': 1
            },
            {
                'film': "Первому игроку приготовиться, 2018",
                'seen': false,
                'id': 2
            },
            {
                'film': "Аватар, 2009",
                'seen': false,
                'id': 3
            },
            {
                'film': "Волк с УолСтрит, 2013",
                'seen': false,
                'id': 4
            },
            {
                'film': "Аквамен, 2018",
                'seen': false,
                'id': 5
            },
            {
                'film': "Джон Уик, 2014",
                'seen': false,
                'id': 6
            },
            {
                'film': "Прибытие, 2016",
                'seen': true,
                'id': 7
            }
        ],
        search: ''
     },
   
    computed:{
    //отфильтровать массив при поиске
      filteredMovies: function() {
        let filtered = this.movies;
            if (this.search) {
                filtered = this.movies.filter(
                m => m.film.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search) > -1);
            }
        return filtered;
        
    //отфильтровать текущий массив и отрисовать в новом массиве
        // return this.movies.filter(function(movie) {
        //     return !movie.seen;
        //   })

      },
      watched: function() {
        return this.movies.filter(function(movie) {
          return movie.seen;
        }); 
      },
    },
    methods: {
           
    }
  });
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #444;
    background-color: #696b65;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 50px 20px;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .container{
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto 40px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 40px 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    background-color: #f4f7fc;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .todo-title{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #f65c65;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  
  form{
    overflow: overlay;
  }
  
  form label{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  
  .btn, input {
    line-height: 2em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px 0;
    padding: 0.2em 1em;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  
  input[type='text'] {
    border: 1px solid #ddd; 
    min-width: 80%;
    transition: all ease-in 0.25s;
  }
  
  input:focus{
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #a3b1ff;
  }
  
  input::placeholder{
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    font-style: italic;
  }
  
  .btn{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold; 
    cursor: pointer;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
  }
  
  .btn-add {
    background: #ddd;
    color: #fefefe;
    border-color: #ddd;
    min-width: 17%;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all ease-in 0.25s;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    line-height: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.3em 0.3em;
    float: right;
  }
  
  .btn-add.active{
    background: #6664ff;
    border-color: #6664ff;
    pointer-events: visible;
  }
  
  .btn-add.active:hover{
    background: #4442f6;
    border-color: #4442f6;
  }
  
  .btn-add:active{
    transform: scale(0.95);
  }
  .control-buttons{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .btn-secondary{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
  
  .btn-secondary:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #f4586e;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    transition: all ease-in 0.25s;
  }
  
  .btn-secondary:hover:after{
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  
  ul.container__movieList{
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  
  ul.container__movieList li{
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    background: #e0e8f5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-left: 38px; 
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-right: 49px; 
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  ul.container__movieList.archived li{
    background: #fff;
  }
  
  .container__movieList__film{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
  }
  
  
  ul.container__movieList li .delete{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #f56468;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all ease-in 0.25s;
  }
    
  .container__movieList__seen{
    position: absolute; 
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  
  .container__movieList__seen + label {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #cfdcec;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  
  .container__movieList__seen:checked + label:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 3px;
    width: 6px;
    border: solid #fc6c48;
    border-width: 0 0 2px 2px;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  
  .container__movieList__seen:checked + label:after{
    display: block;
  }
  
  .container__movieList__seen:checked ~ .container__movieList__film{
    color: #888;
    text-decoration: line-through
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="movieApp.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="app">
            <div class="container">
                <button>Рандом</button>
                <input 
                    type="text"
                    class="input-todo" 
                    v-model="search"
                    placeholder="Поиск по фильмам"
                >
                <button>Фильтр</button>
        
        
                <div>
                    <ul class="container__movieList">
                        <li 
                            v-for="(movie, index) in filteredMovies" 
                            v-bind:key="movie.film"
                        >
                            <input 
                                class="container__movieList__seen" 
                                v-bind:id="'movie_' + movie.id" 
                                v-model="movie.seen" 
                                type="checkbox"
                            >
                            <label v-bind:for="'movie_' + movie.id"></label>
                            <span class="container__movieList__film">{{ movie.film }}</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        
        
                <div>
                    <p>Просмотренные</p>
                    <ul class="container__movieList archived">
                        <li 
                            v-for="(movie, index) in watched" 
                            v-bind:key="movie.film"
                        >
                            <input 
                                class="container__movieList__seen" 
                                v-bind:id="'movie_' + movie.id" 
                                v-model="movie.seen" 
                                type="checkbox"
                            >
                            <label v-bind:for="'movie_' + movie.id"></label>
                            <span class="container__movieList__film">{{ movie.film }}</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
    <script src="movieApp.js"></script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
filteredMovies: function() {
        let filtered = this.movies;
            // if (this.search) {
                filtered = this.movies.filter(
                m => m.film.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search) > -1 && !m.seen);
            
        return filtered;
```